# Laptop to TTL output

Tags: ttl

I need to control a board using a TTL level signal from a laptop. I have seen USB to TTL mini-boards, but none explicitly for use with a standard laptop. What is the best way to do this, and what software is available?

My board needs a TTL signal with switching speeds up to 10kHz. I need it to modulated a laser beam.

Comment: If you are referring at USB to TTL mini board as USB serial converter, then they are for standard PC, laptop. But it snot clear what kind of TTL output you want, how you will control it?

Comment: I don't understand if: a) you want a board that converts USB to TTL serial data, and you have a MCU that uses that serial data (frequency, duty cycle) to configure the TTL output, or b) you want a board that already outputs a TTL with a determined frequency and duty cyle (selected through USB)?

In other words: does your board come with a MCU?

Comment: I want something that plugs into a laptop and is powered from the laptop, and which outputs a TTL level signal to my laser driver board. I have no idea what the circuit of the laser drive might be - only i/f specs

Comment: Worth trying the headphone jack followed by a pulse squarer; might or might not meet your needs, but it's right there and easy to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it seems the only thing that comes close is the "[USB to TTL Serial Cable](https://www.maplin.co.uk/p/usb-to-ttl-serial-cable-cable-n74de)" - aptly named. Cheap enough to throw away if it doesn't work. The 3V3 output should be able to drive a TTL "1" at above 2V4

Comment: No, this will not really solve the problem.  Those are designed out output an asynchronous serial stream, which is not what you need given its forced framing interruptions.  Nor will you be able to "bit bang" the control lines fast enough across USB latency.  It's vaguely possible that if a particular chip offers an alternate *synchronous* mode that might work, but typically synchronous serial interfaces (apart from those made for audio) insert gaps between words as well.

Comment: The best solutions would be those that allow you to put the timing critical software in an MCU on the far end of the USB cable, second to that would be data streaming solutions, like CY7C68013A logic analyzer with an alternate firmware to run it backwards as a generator.

Comment: This may still be a viable option as the OP was considering using the ASYNCH character framing to generate his laser control pulses.  It would be TTL level (some are at 5V) and it would not require further supplies to provide the pulse train.  It would also provide 2 handshake output signals for other indicators etc. and 4 digital inputs for sensing things.

Answer (score 1):

To modulate a laser you will need accurate timing. Your laptop probably won't do this well if you aren't running a real-time operating system (RTOS).

Normally this task would be farmed out to a dedicated timer. If you had an Arduino board to hand this should be easy to knock up and you could then send a simple serial command via the IDE to adjust the duty cycle or frequency.

Comment: I was thinking of something like an RS232 output running at (say) 9600 baud. The modulation sequence is quite short

Comment: The Arduino should be able to handle that.

Comment: @DirkBruere What modulation sequence? The Rs232 outputs a signal according to characters sent.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yes - I was thinking of bodging the output by sending character streams. But am looking for something better if available

Comment: @DirkBruere How better? More pretty looking? With galvanic isolation? Please define how one TTL signal is better than other.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I do not want to have a separate PSU. I want TTL levels and not RS232. I would prefer something that has s/w to drive it easily rather than having to write my own.

Comment: @DirkBruere You have messed everything. a) To have a separate PSU you need a galvanically isolated converter. b)The only available software is the virtual COM port driver and then you send characters with Terminal Window c) TTL output stands for TTL level, not RS232 level, but the protocol is RS232 as you wish.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič No - all I need is a common ground. I know what TTL stands for - do you know what RS232 voltage levels are? I want a direct TTL input into my laser driver board without having to add another board powered by another PSU. This whole setup is supposed to be reasonably portable.

Comment: RS232 levels are -12 to +12 V. Arduino can be powered from USB.

Answer (score 0):

National Instruments sells some [multifunction I/O boards](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/select/multifunction-io-category#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&orderBy:&pageView:grid&pageSize:&) that should work nicely for your application (or others since this answer is 1 year late). They start from around $150 for the USB devices, and I and others in my research group have used the USB 6000 series devices. I use it to control an optical shutter at up to 50 Hz, but these can go up in the tens of kHz as I understand. They can easily be used with their own drivers or with Labview

Comment: There are plenty of < $10 solutions for this problem, essentially any microcontroller board can do it.

Comment: I bet! Yeah like that guy mentioned Arduino I'm sure could work just fine.